How to execute `typescript.goToSourceDefinition` in neovim with lspconfig
I'd like to jump to the actual implementation typescript function in neovim instead of the type definition. From what I've read I must execute the "typescript.goToSourceDefinition".  I'm executing it with
local params = vim.lsp.util.make_position_params()
vim.lsp.buf.execute_command {
    command = "typescript.goToSourceDefinition",
    arguments = { params.textDocument.uri, params.position },
}

Adding vim.print(params) confirms that I'm executing this code when I've hit the right key bindings and that the value is what I expected it to be.  But nothing happens after that... No other messages.  Nothing.  Replacing it with vim.lsp.buf.definition() takes me to the .d.ts file as expected so its not like my LSP is set up incorrectly.
